# TableStorage Namespace

Tags: azure-table-storage

If I use this namespace, it works fine

```
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage;
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Auth;
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Table;

namespace TableStorage
{
    public class Troupe : TableEntity
```

This is the old namespace, as I understand it.

, but if instead enable using this newer namespace

```
using Azure.Data.Tables;

namespace TableStorage
{
    public class Troupe : TableEntity
    {
```

I get this:

```
error CS0509: 'Troupe': cannot derive from sealed type 'TableEntity'
```

Any pointers as to how I should correctly do this?;)

Comment: Google is your friend: https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/blob/main/sdk/tables/Azure.Data.Tables/MigrationGuide.md

Answer (score 1):

With that version you cannot inherit the class, you must implement the interface:

```
public class Troupe: ITableEntity {
}
```